# Under what conditions is a user invited to "share a link to this question"?

Tags: support, user-interface, unanswered-questions, sharing

> Know someone who can answer? Share a link to this question via email, Google+, Twitter, or Facebook.

This notice occasionally appears under a question with no answers.  But not often. What are the criteria for displaying it?

I was recently amused by this notice under a fresh spam post on Drupal Answers. Discussion in [the Tavern](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3593461#3593461) revealed that it's not necessarily shown to every user, but we couldn't figure our what triggers it.

Comment: Yeah, that's interesting...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A little research, and after observation, I have noticed the following:

- Date has nothing to do with the criteria. [A post from 2009 has that notice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441739/ascx-with-gridview-and-detailsview).
- It only shows in posts with zero answers.
- Being logged in has nothing to do with this, I showed a post in a different browser while I am not logged in and in a different machine with a different IP while not logged in and I still got the notice.
- It does not show on closed questions. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30884218/how-to-change-old-ios-platform-to-new-ios-platform)
- Score does not make any difference, [a question with a score of -11 shows that notice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30884218/how-to-change-old-ios-platform-to-new-ios-platform)
- It does not show on meta sites.

So, to sum that up, it shows on any **open question with zero answers on a normal site**.

Note that the notice does not have the yellow background in all sites which makes it easy to miss. So look closely in any question that fits the criteria above and you will find it, hopefully.

Comment: Thanks. Turns out, I had a userscript blocking that page element. I saw that noticed when the script was temporarily disabled...  At least we got documentation here, thanks to your effort.