# What happened to "depends on everyone sharing their knowledge" message? Can this be changed on per-site basis?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, sharing, share-this

As I read in [Adam Lear's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289217/what-is-this-can-you-help-message-above-the-answer-box/289234#289234) to the question [What is this “Can you help?” message above the answer box?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/289217), at some point in the past, the message was tested:

> Can you help? SiteName depends on everyone sharing their knowledge. If you're able to answer this question, please do!

It was displayed [on questions with no answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258957/under-what-conditions-is-a-user-invited-to-share-a-link-to-this-question/258966#258966) as an alternative to this message:

> Know someone who can answer? Share a link to this question via email, Google+, Twitter, or Facebook.

1. Were the plans to use the new version abandoned. Or are there some plans to switch to the new version?
2. Also, would it be possible to choose one of these forms or change the message completely *on a specific site,* if the local community prefers a different wording?

---

I have tagged this [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) since I am asking also for possibility to change the message on a specific site (rather than network-wide). I suspect this is not possible at the moment - if it is, I should probably retag [support](/questions/tagged/support).

Comment: I am not sure whether there are some other sites where users were not satisfied with this message. One of the reasons why I posted this was the post on MathOverflow Meta:[Why do we link to Twitter, Facebook or Google+ below every question?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3095). This post is currently at score 21 (+24/-3), so it seems that at least some users of that site are not happy with the current wording.

Comment: Your question is asking *two* things—which makes it poorly phrased. I agree with the first point (I like the updated wording), but I disagree with the second point (actual wording aside, I think that whatever message is displayed should apply to all sites).